# Unable to configure Keystone 6 with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, keystonejs, keystonejs6

I'm trying to set up Keystone using MongoDB as the database. Upon running `keystone-next`, the command errors out with the following error message: `Error: Invalid db configuration. Please specify db.provider as either "sqlite" or "postgresql" at getDBProvider`.

There's no much clarity on their docs on what values to pass as `db.provider` to use MongoDB as database.

Here are the contents of `keystone.ts`:

```js
import { config, createSchema } from '@keystone-next/keystone/schema'
import 'dotenv/config'

const databaseUrl =
  process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'mongodb://localhost/keystone-project'

const sessionConfig = {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 90,
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET || 'keystone-project-secret'
}

export default config({
  server: {
    cors: {
      origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL],
      credentials: true
    }
  },
  db: {
    provider: 'mongoose',
    url: databaseUrl
    // TODO: add data seeding here
  },
  lists: createSchema({
    // Schema items go here
  }),
  ui: {
    // Change this for roles}
    isAccessAllowed: () => true
  }
  // Add session values here
})
```

Here are the project's dependencies from `package.json`:

```json
{
...
"dependencies": {
    "@keystone-next/admin-ui": "^14.1.3",
    "@keystone-next/auth": "^31.0.0",
    "@keystone-next/cloudinary": "^6.0.6",
    "@keystone-next/fields": "^14.0.0",
    "@keystone-next/keystone": "^24.0.1",
    "@keystone-next/types": "^24.0.0",
    "@keystonejs/server-side-graphql-client": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "next": "^11.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "stripe": "^8.169.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.15.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^12.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Keystone 6 (the version you're using here) doesn't yet support Mongo. You need to specify either PostgreSQL (`postgresql`) or SQLite (`sqlite`) as the DB provider.

Version 6 switched to using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io) as the underlying ORM layer, giving the team a consistent way to access different DB platforms and letting us focus higher level functionality.

The Prisma team are working hard on adding Mongo support and the functionality was recently [released as a preview](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.27.0). However some features (programmatic DB creation and some others I think) are blocking it's use with Keystone. [PR #6102](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/6102) tracks the progress on the Keystone side or [#1277](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1277) over in the Prisma project. I can't offer and estimate on when this will land but it's being actively progressed.